# ReportEvent returns error 'invalid parameter'

Tags: windows, winapi

I wonder to set event into existed Event Log. These is code:

```
_ev_hndl = RegisterEventSource(NULL, L"Application");

WCHAR msg_[] = L"Hello";
if (!ReportEvent(_ev_hndl, ev_type, 1, 0, NULL, 1, 0, (LPCWSTR*)&msg_, NULL)) {
    std::cout << "error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
}
```

But I get an error: 87 (invalid parameter)

Comment: You are calling `GetLastError` too late. Please call it **immediately** after a Windows API call fails (if the documentation says so).

Comment: I get fail after calling `ReportEvent`, `RegisterEventSource` returns valid handle

Comment: Yes. You are calling `GetLastError` too late. Can't you see that you call other functions in between `ReportEvent` returning, and your call to `GetLastError`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was close to msg parameter. Right code:

```
LPCTSTR strings[] = { TEXT("abcdefg") };

if (!ReportEvent(_ev_hndl, EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, 0, 0, NULL, 1, 0, strings, NULL)) {...
```